# Verificar caracter em Text Box para marcar em um radioButton

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Gostaria de saber como verificar se a letra preenchida em um `textBox` é A ou B para conforme o resultado dar `Checked` em uma `RadioButton`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
radioButtonA.Checked = textBox.Text == "A";
radioButtonB.Checked = textBox.Text == "B";
```

Comment: Acho que também pode ser "B", pela pergunta dele, então não seria 

`radioButton.Checked = (textBox.Text == "A" || textBox.Text == "B");` ?

Comment: A ideia é a mesma, mas obrigado pela observação =D

Comment: Hahaha por nada :) Vou apagar a minha e deixar só a sua, pois está mais simples